# Statistical model for axis angle rotations

Tags: euclidean, rotation, circular-statistics

I would like to describe a large number of measurements of rotations $\textbf{x}_i$. Each rotation is described by its rotation axis $\textbf{v} =\frac{\textbf{x}}{|\textbf{x}|}$ and the rotation angle $a =|\textbf{x}|$ around this axis.

Distributions like von Mises-Fisher and Bingham only describes how the directions are distributed, but I would also like to describe the rotation angle's dependency on direction. So I am looking to find $P(\textbf{x}) = P(\textbf{x}|\textbf{v})P(\textbf{v})$, where $\textbf{x}\in R^3$ and $\textbf{v}$ is a point on the unit sphere. (edit: I misunderstood the $SO(3)$ notation)

I know $P(\textbf{v})$ can be described with fx. von Mises-Fisher, but what are some usual candidates for the distribution $P(\textbf{x}|\textbf{v})$? Or is there already a combined distribution for direction vectors with magnitude?

I could add that some of my data looks like a 3D hourglass shape, so I cannot just use a 3D normal distribution.

(edit: According to Wikipedia von Mises-Fisher is a probability density function on a random *unit* vector. So as I understand it only describes the axis of most likely rotation, not the amount rotated.)

Comment: What is $SO(3)$?

Comment: I am missing the distinction you are making between $\mathbf{v}\in SO(3)$, which by definition is a *rotation* (not just a rotation axis!), and $\mathbf{x}$, which you describe as a rotation. If $\mathbf{v}$ is intended to be just a rotation *axis*, then it can be identified either with a point on the sphere $S^2$ or on its quotient the projective plane, but it's not an element of $SO(3)$.  Perhaps you are looking for something like a [von Mises-Fisher distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Mises%E2%80%93Fisher_distribution)?

Answer (score 2):

A rotation in $SO(3)$ can be represented by a [unit quaternion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions_and_spatial_rotation), which is a pair of points on the [3-sphere](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3-sphere).  Therefore you can use the [Bingham distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bingham_distribution) in 4 dimensions as a distribution over 3D rotations.