# Is there an "antipodal" conditional disintegration of the von Mises Fisher distribution?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, references, circular-statistics, conditioning, von-mises-distribution

For more on conditional disintegration, cf. e.g. the references [1] [2], or these questions [[a]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/108740/conditional-probability-and-the-disintegration-theorem) [[b]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3834037/from-disintegration-to-conditioning) on math stackexchange.

> **Question:** For the [von-Mises Fisher distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Mises%E2%80%93Fisher_distribution), is there a conditional disintegration via [antipodal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antipodal_point) pairs of points? I.e. so each conditional distribution would be a Bernoulli and have as values the two points of an [antipodal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antipodal_point) pair?

**Observation:** At least in the case that $\kappa$ (concentration) equals $0$, and thus the [von Mises-Fisher distribution reduces to the uniform distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Mises%E2%80%93Fisher_distribution#The_uniform_hypersphere_distribution) on the (hyper)sphere, the answer would clearly seem to be yes. Namely the resulting conditional distributions of the disintegration would just be "fair coins", i.e. Bernoullis giving equal probability to each antipode.

**Comment:** A reference would suffice, although something like a derivation / calculation would be amazing of course. If it's relevant, I'm most interested in the case that $p=3$ (i.e. distributions on the 2D sphere in 3D space).

Slightly related question: [Statistical model for axis angle rotations](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/123886/statistical-model-for-axis-angle-rotations) (conditioning is on a single direction, not antipodal pair of directions)

[1] [*Conditioning as disintegration*, J. T. Chang and D. Pollard, Statistica Neerlandica (1997) Vol. 51, nr. 3, pp. 287±317](http://www.stat.yale.edu/%7Ejtc5/papers/ConditioningAsDisintegration.pdf)

[2] sections 2.2. and 2.3 of [*Exact Bayesian Inference by Symbolic Disintegration*, Chung-chieh Shan and Norman Ramsey, POPL’17, January 15–21, 2017, Paris, France
ACM. 978-1-4503-4660-3/17/01](https://homes.luddy.indiana.edu/ccshan/rational/disintegrator.pdf). http://dx.doi.org/10.1145/3009837.3009852